# Why did my post closed due to code programming?

Tags: discussion

I made few posts where I was not sure about how to use a specific hypotesis testing on R and my post has got closed but I've seen a lot of post regarding about some error output error and they haven't been closed.So I'd like to know what makes a post gets down due to 'code programming'.

Comment: Which posts are you referring to?  Your most recent closed post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557680 explicitly asks "I think I misused prop test. What should I do?"  That appears to ask for help with your `R` code.  If not, the problem lies in ambiguous communication, not in this site's policies.  Please be aware that when a question is closed, the site permits us to post only one standard reason, even when the question ought to be closed for many reasons.

Comment: My last post has got closed .https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557680/how-should-i-compare-counting-values. This one not even being programming based  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155523/r-prop-test-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect.

Comment: I see no evidence that https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155523/r-prop-test-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect was ever closed, nor that it's even a question that you've asked!

Comment: It was not closed, where is the cap which differs a programming based asking from a question where use coding but doesn't got closed?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155523 is about. It's statistical in nature because it asks about how to compute p-values and the statistical meaning of an warning message. Answering these questions requires statistical knowledge to answer. Asking someone to write R code for you is just a programming question. (But if you want to know something else, then perhaps you have an on-topic question -- but https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155523/ seems to be a duplicate, because it addresses what the Warning in your question means)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic explains CV Policy: "If your question is about Programming, ask on Stack Overflow. If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about the implementation of an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain."

Comment: This kind of distinction was made in closing your post, and I don't see that your question here raises any new issues.  There is a grey area where it's hard to decide and no doubt some decisions not to close now appear wrong to some people, but discussing marginal cases can only be fruitful if based on close study of specific examples.

Comment: ... and some decisions to close now appear wrong to some people ...